# Uppercase to Lowercase in URL

Tags: rewrite-rules

i have a function that creates a modRewrite rule

```
function markets_rewrite_url() {

add_rewrite_rule( '(.+?)/symbol/(.+?)/exchange/(.*)', 'index.php?&pagename=$matches[1]&symbol=$matches[2]&exchange=$matches[3]', 'top' );
add_rewrite_tag( '%symbol%', '([\-\w+]*)' );
add_rewrite_tag( '%exchange%', '([\-\w+]*)' );

}
```

this works fine but to rewrite the rule but i will want =$matches[2] and =$matches[3] in lower case if it appears in uppercase

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is NOT mod_rewrite rule, it's WordPress rewrite rule and it proposes to parse variables from URL to wp_query (most of the time).

You can apply your logic during `parse_query` filter hook., something like this.

```
add_filter( 'parse_query', function( WP_Query $wp_query ) : WP_Query {
    foreach ( [ 'symbol', 'exchange' ] as $key ) {
        if ( '' !== $wp_query->get( $key ) ) {
            $wp_query->set( $key, strtolower( $wp_query->get( $key ) ) );
        }
    }
    return $wp_query;
});
```